# mongoDB Rename embedded field

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

how do we rename embedded fields using C# with mongoDB ? An example of document **Person** would be:

```
{
Id: 1,
LastName: "Smith",
FirstName: "John",
Orders: {
         Id: 1,
         Name: "Trousers" // I want to rename **Name** into **Something**
    }
}
```

With mongoDB syntax, it would be something like

```
db.Users.update({}, {$rename:{"Orders.Name":"Orders.Something"}},true, true)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at

```
 MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Rename(string oldElementName, 
                                       string newElementName)
```

It returns an IUpdateQuery, which you can pass to collection.Update() and rename your field.  The C# Update builder has every special command you can use in mongo as a callable function to build your query.

The Builders namespace is a great namespace in the MongoDB C# driver.  It includes Query and Update builders.  You can chain commands and do things like this:

```
 Update.Set("indexsize", indexSize).Set("extractsize", extractedFileSize);
```

or

```
 Query.GT("filesize", 200000).In(bsonArray);
```