# MongoDB Shell Script Update all field Names where there is space in field name

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

Using `MongoDB` shell script 3.2, how can I update all fields where field names have a `space replace those with underscore`?

```
{
"Some Field": "value",
"OtherField" :"Value",
"Another Field" : "Value"
}
```

update the above document as below

```
{
"Some_Field": "value",
"OtherField" :"Value",
"Another_Field" : "Value"
}
```

rename field can be done with something like this

```
db.CollectionName.update( { _id: 1 }, { $rename: { 'nickname': 'alias', 'cell': 'mobile' } } )
```

Challenging part here is `filter`, how to come up with a `filter` where there is a space in field name

Comment: You can not update field name. You can add a new field with changed name, the way you want. Then remove the old fields.

Comment: Can't I do something like find a field with space set new filed  (duplicate of same with underscore) and delete the one with space?

Comment: @Shrabanee so how can I come up with query to find all fields or all documents which have a field names with space?

Comment: I don't think that is also possible. I never tried such query. May be you need to achieve this manually .

Comment: looks like there is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901701/mongodb-rename-embedded-field

Comment: I am not sure about how to use the solution in the question. Never used such query. Try and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs a two-step approach. First, you need a mechanism to get a list of all the keys with a space in your collection. Once you get the list, construct an object that maps those keys to their renamed values. You can then use that object as your **[`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)** operator document. Consider using **[`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)** to get the list of keys with spaces.

The following **[`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)** operation will populate a separate collection with all the filtered keys as the `_id` values:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "CollectionName",
    "map": function() {
        var regxp = /\s/;
        for (var key in this) { 
            if (key.match(regxp)) {
                emit(key, null); 
            }
        }
    },
    "reduce": function() {}, 
    "out": "filtered_keys"
})
```

To get a list of all the spaced keys, run distinct on the resulting collection:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["Some Field", "Another Field"]
```

---

Now given the list above, you can assemble your update document by creating an object that will have its properties set within a loop. Normally your update document will have this structure:

```
var update = {
    "$rename": {
        "Some Field": "Some_Field",
        "Another Field": "Another_Field"        
    }
}
```

Thus

```
var update = { "$rename": {} };
db[mr.result].distinct("_id").forEach(function (key){
    update["$rename"][key] = key.replace(/ /g,"_");
});
```

which you can then use in your update as

```
db.CollectionName.update({ }, update, false, true );
```

Comment: key.replace(" ", "_") only replaces first occurrence of space, there could be fields like "Some Field Value"

Comment: @HaBo Thanks for noticing, I've updated my answer with a global scope regex in the replace() method.

Comment: Welcome you have to change this as well key.match(r) r should be replaced with regxp

Comment: Oh dear, so many sloppy mistakes :P Thanks once again for catching these

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @chridam that was a excellent query.

Had to make small changes to run query, Full working query.

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "MyCollectionName",
    "map": function() {
        var regxp = /\s/;
        for (var key in this) { 
            if (key.match(regxp)) {
                emit(key, null); 
            }
        }
    },
    "reduce": function() {}, 
    "out": "filtered_keys"
})

db[mr.result].distinct("_id")

var update = { "$rename": {} };
db[mr.result].distinct("_id").forEach(function (key){
    update["$rename"][key] = key.replace(/\s+/g, "_");
});

//print(update)

db.MyCollectionName.update({ }, update, false, true );
```